# Making a chessboard with two queens on it

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im looking to make an 8 x 8 chessboard in my terminal. I've made the proper 8 x 8 grid but can't add the two queens now as 1's

I keep trying as you can see in the code arrayz[0][1] = 1. I'm wondering if the problem is with my looping or there's an easy way to insert two ones into the problem.

```
const generateBoard= function(){

  let arrayz = []
  let set= []
  let newArray = []


  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){

      newArray.push(0)
  } 
  for (y = 0; y < 8; y++){
      //newArray[0][1] = 1
      arrayz.push(newArray)  
      arrayz[0][1] = 1 //my failed code that im trying to use to input a single one

  }  
  return arrayz
}  

console.log(generateBoard(whiteQueen, blackQueen))



[ [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ] //what i keep getting
  [ [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ] ]//what i want
```

Comment: You're pushing the same row over and over again. You should add a _new_ row in each loop.

Answer (score 9):

This code creates only one board row array, `newArray`, rather than the desired 8. All 8 entries in the array `arrayz` are just references to `newArray`. Modifying any one of them will modify all 8, which is obviously not the intent.

In fact, printing the output here on Stack Overflow shows:

```
[
  [
    /**id:2**/
    0,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],
  /**ref:2**/,
  /**ref:2**/,
  /**ref:2**/,
  /**ref:2**/,
  /**ref:2**/,
  /**ref:2**/,
  /**ref:2**/
]
```

Which labels each reference array as a pointer to the first element which has the id 2. Here's the runnable example:

```js
const generateBoard= function(){

  let arrayz = []
  let set= []
  let newArray = []


  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){

      newArray.push(0)
  } 
  for (y = 0; y < 8; y++){
      //newArray[0][1] = 1
      arrayz.push(newArray)  
      arrayz[0][1] = 1 //my failed code that im trying to use to input a single one

  }  
  return arrayz
}  

console.log(generateBoard())
```

The reference problem can be addressed in a variety of ways. For example, changing

```
arrayz.push(newArray)
```

to

```
arrayz.push(newArray.slice());
```

makes a true copy of `newArray` using [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), eliminating the unwanted aliasing.

---

Another way to make a 2d grid of zeroes is using the [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) constructor, [`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const board = Array(8).fill().map(() => Array(8).fill(0));
board[0][1] = 1;
console.log(board);
```